# pandas dataframe how to add diff column which calculates difference between two consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two rows, and I want to add one more row which shows the difference between two rows.

```py
 data = [
            (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
            (10, 30, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100)
            ]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "f", "g"])
```

following works, but it adds extra row with `nan`

```py
pd.concat([df, df.diff()])
```

```
      a     b     c     d     d     f      g
0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0   70.0
1  10.0  30.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0  100.0
0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
1   0.0  10.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   30.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) always yields a first row of NaNs, just drop it:

```
out = pd.concat([df, df.diff().iloc[1:]])
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c     d     d     f      g
0  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0   70.0
1  10.0  30.0  30.0  40.0  50.0  60.0  100.0
1   0.0  10.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   30.0
```

If you really have only two rows, you can hardcode the subtraction:

```
out = df.copy() # optional, you can also assign to df
out.loc['diff'] = df.iloc[1]-df.iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
       a   b   c   d   d   f    g
0     10  20  30  40  50  60   70
1     10  30  30  40  50  60  100
diff   0  10   0   0   0   0   30
```